How to run websocket server in separate Thread?
I'm creating a desktop application in Python with a GUI written in Vue 3, and I need to run a WebSocket server in a separate thread. The issue is that the WebSocket server must continuously listen for incoming connections to enable real-time communication with the client, and I'm not sure how to run it in a new thread, which is necessary because otherwise, the GUI won't start. Does anyone have any idea how this should be implemented? Because I'm out of ideas on how it should be done.
Main Code:
import asyncio
import webview
import threading
from services.HttpServer import HttpServerService
from services.WebSocket import WebSocketService
 
def on_loaded(window_ready):
    webview.windows[0].events.loaded -= on_loaded
    print('Val', window_ready);
    if (window_ready):
        webview.windows[0].set_window_size(width=1200, height=800)
 
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.http_server_thread = None
        self.websocket_thread = None
        self.client_ui_thread = None
        self.websocket = None
        self.client_ui = None
        self.webview = webview
 
    async def start(self):
        self.http_server_thread = threading.Thread(target=HttpServerService("127.0.0.1", 8001).start)
        self.http_server_thread.daemon = True  # Set the thread as daemon
        self.http_server_thread.start()
 
        self.websocket = WebSocketService("127.0.0.1", 8008)
        self.websocket_thread = threading.Thread(target=await self.websocket.start)
        self.websocket_thread.daemon = True  # Set the thread as daemon
        self.websocket_thread.start()
 
        self.client_ui = webview.create_window("CrowdQuant", url="http://127.0.0.1:8001", width=1024, height=770,
                                               resizable=False, frameless=True)
        self.client_ui.events.loaded += lambda: self.websocket.on_message(variable_name="window_ready",
                                                                          handle_message_fn=lambda
                                                                              window_ready: on_loaded(window_ready))
 
        self.client_ui_thread = threading.Thread(target=webview.start)  # gui="cef"
        self.client_ui_thread.daemon = True  # Set the thread as daemon
        self.client_ui_thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(App().start())

WebSocketService Code:
import json
import asyncio
import websockets
 
class WebSocketService:
    def __init__(self, address="127.0.0.0", port=8008):
        self.socket = None
        self.url = (address, port)
        self.variable_name = None
        self.handle_message_fn = None
        self.server = None
        self.clients = set()
 
    async def start(self):
        await self.start_server()
        await self.start_client()
 
    async def start_server(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.server = await websockets.serve(self.handle_client_connection, self.url[0], self.url[1])
                print(f"WebSocket server started at ws://{self.url[0]}:{self.url[1]}")
                await self.server.wait_closed()
            except OSError:
                print(f"Address {self.url[0]}:{self.url[1]} already in use. Retrying...")
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
 
    async def handle_client_connection(self, websocket):
        self.clients.add(websocket)
        try:
            async for message in websocket:
                await self.handle_message(message)
        finally:
            self.clients.remove(websocket)
 
    async def stop(self):
        await self.stop_client()
        await self.stop_server()
 
    async def stop_server(self):
        if self.server:
            self.server.close()
            await self.server.wait_closed()
 
    @staticmethod
    def on_error(error):
        print('WebSocket error:', error)


It’s already async. Isn’t that sufficient?
